# Webpack is erroring when I attempt to import a directory containing modules

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to create a small npm library to make interfacing with an API a little neater. My folder structure is as follows...

```
dist/
  index.js
src/
  index.js
  endpoints/
    endpoint1.js
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

Within my src/index.js file I have..

```
import {endpoint1} from './endpoints'

module.exports = class lib {
 ...
}
```

When I *npm run build* (which runs *webpack --display-error-details --mode production*) webpack throws a big error saying **"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './endpoints' in 'my\project\dir\src'**.

My webpack.config.js file currently looks like...

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [

            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/endpoints')
        ],
        extensions: ['.js']
    }
};
```

I can see similar questions have been asked before and the resolutions listed don't seem to work for me so I thought I'd post it incase im making a rookie error. If any more info is required just say! Sorry if it's fairly wall of texty. Thanks.

Comment: The module name is "endpoint1"

Comment: Should post that as an answer, Jonas Wilms. I think it's valid as it solves his problem

Comment: `'./endpoints'` refers to `./endpoints/index.js` because it's a directory. You either want to import `'./endpoints/endpoint1'` or create `index.js` that whould export `endpoint1`

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies! Is there no way I can import a directory containing modules? Explicitly importing every module from the directory will be a bit cumbersome...

Comment: @ToastedToast I addressed it in my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct import would be:

```
 import endpoint1 from 'endpoint1';
```

By using [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules) you tell Webpack to look up *non relative paths* in that folder. The module name is "enpoint1".

But actually you should only do this with libraries that you use across your project, for an endpoint a relative import will be appropriate:

```
 import endpoint1 from "./endpoints/endpoint1";
```

Comment: I do not understand why non relative paths should be in that folder. How is this folder so special? It's possible but seems odd. Normally non-relative paths refer to `node_modules`. People will be confused.

Comment: Agreed. an alias would be more appropriate here, or importing `./enpoint/endpoint1`. Will extend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`import {endpoint1} from './endpoints'` means this:
import from file `./endpoints/index.js` something that is exported under the name `enpoint1` in that file. If you import directory then it refers to `index.js` under that directory, not to all other files. It doesn't exist in your setup.

Names inside `{}` refer to named imports. This goes only for `es6 modules`-style imports like `import {...} from`. If you ommit `{}` then you import the  default. `CommonJs`-style imports like `const {...} = require('')` work differently. CommonJs does not have named imports and exports. It just will import default from that file and then fetch a field via object destructuring.

What you export is something unnamed(i.e. default) from file `./endpoints/enpoint1.js`

Something is unnamed because you use `module.exports =` which is `CommonJS`-style export. CommonJS does not support named exports. This is equevalent to `export default class lib ...` in `es6 modules`-style exports.

**IF you want to import many files under directory** you can consider these solutions:

1) Often single import points are created. You make a `index.js` file. In it you import manually every file under the directoy that you want to export. Then you export it under names. Like this:

```
import a from './a.js';
import b from './b.js';
import c from './c.js';

export { a, b, c };
```

Then it will work

2) In some rare cases in might make sence to use `fs.readdir` or `fs.readdirSync` to scan the entire directory and dynamicly `require` files in a loop. Use it only if you must. E.g. db migrations.